# How to control processes in a Hyper-V VM's console?

Tags: powershell, build-process, automation, hyper-v

I want to script the building of a Hyper-V VM as part of a build process.  Specifically I need to be able to launch processes, perhaps sending keys into the VM as well, but as long as I can launch processes with specific command-lines I think I'll be good.

I'm already aware of this useful library: http://www.codeplex.com/PSHyperv, but it seems to be all VM-controller-level operations rather than controlling the OS within the VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using [PowerShell Remoting](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/winpsh/remote.mspx).

Comment: Cool. My first inclination was to respond with "but how do I start PowerShell remote server on the VM so that I can remote to it?" It would be a chicken-and-egg problem.  But since I can start with a VM template image that auto launches it, I guess this will work. :)  Thanks.